# Is there a way to output a boolean through USB in Java?

Tags: java, usb

I am making a simulation for my second year project which needs to output a boolean value through USB to an arduino. I was wondering what the best way to do this is and if I need to use a library or something? I am using java. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Boolean through USB? as in send a 1 or a 0 on the serial port connected to the USB ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get a 1 or 0 to be sent to an arduino needs to read the this value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900950/how-to-send-data-to-com-port-using-java or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264277/java-serial-communication-on-windows

Comment: USB uses differential line to send data. You will need some adapter to convert signal from USB to TTL levels. For example you can use FTDI chip based USB - UART adapter and some java library that supports bit bang mode for it. https://github.com/KeyBridge/lib-usb3-ftdi seems to support bit bang according to readme file.

Answer (score 0):

Many arduinos have a USB serial port, so use the port on the USB - example just changes the Boolean value that is being sent each second.

```
int bool_val = 0;

void setup() {
 // initialize the serial communication:
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // send the value
  Serial.println(bool_val);

  delay(1000);

  // toggle value

  bool_val = !bool_val;

}
```

You can then open the serial of the USB connected from the Arduino to read the values in your java code using something like RXTX 
http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/